# cURL data not working properly

Tags: php, json, curl, file-get-contents

I cannot get html output, what could be the problem? the data coming as label, not an html!

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
$url = 'https://www.cosmetica.com.tr/tr/arama-sonuclari-8697888010218';
$json = curl_get_contents($url);

preg_match_all('@<a ng-href="(.*?)>@si',$json,$source);
print_r($source[0][0]);
```

html output: blabla.com.tr/{{slugify(category.name)}}-c-{{category.id}}
links label coming : e.g. {{slugify(subCategory.name)}}

but the links look html e.g. blabla.com//tr/p-art-net-far-karistirma-fircasi-no25-31770

Comment: try `print_r($source);`

Comment: what type of data are you expecting? can you show some example of it

Comment: The data you get is HTML, not JSON. Why then name your variable `$json`? Good variable names tell you, and your teammates, what information is "stored" inside that variable. They should even make sense to a non computer programmer.

Comment: @B.Desai the contents come in this way 
{{slugify(subCategory.name)}}-sc-{{subCategory.id}}

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - You're right! pre-existing...

Comment: @pinoyCoder it coming in this way
{{slugify(subCategory.name)}}
why links become label?
xxx.com/blabla.html 
why it is not?

Comment: @ismail I'm confused with what you want to achieve, Please elaborate more what you are trying to achieve here.